# Segments.Gender - это не тип

Tags: java

Что тут делать?

У меня есть вот такой класс

```
public class Category {

    public static String gender = "Gender";
    public static String age = "Age";
    public static String income = "Income";

    static enum Gender {
        MALE("MALE"),
        FEMALE("FEMALE");

        private String value;

        Gender(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
    static enum Income {
        A("A"),
        B("B"),
        C("C");

        private String value;

        Income(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Дальше создаю другой класс с cсылкой на этот класс:

```
public class Segments {
public static Category.Gender Gender;
    public static Category.Income Income;
}
```

Дальше хочу создать вот такой массив

```
Segments.Gender[] seg = new Segments.Gender[2];
```

Выдает ошибку - типа `Segments.Gender` - это не тип. Как это исправить?

Comment: Вы лучше опишите, что вы хотите получить. Я пока только вижу странные структуры данных.

Comment: Мне нужно в классе Target реализовать Map<Category, List<Segments>>

Нужно сделать так, чтобы если категория была пол, то сегменты - либо "мужчина" либо "женщина"
Если категория доходо, то сегмент - "доход А", "доход Б"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вынисите энумы в отдельные классы
2. Сделайте поля класса `Category private`
3. Вместо типа `String`, использовать энумы `Gender`, `Income` и `int` для возраста
4. Добавить конструктор, который принимает `Gender`, `Income` и возраст

Примерно так, нужно еще добавить проверки на возраст, но это уже не моя задача:

```
public class Category {
    private Gender gender;
    private int age;
    private Income income;

    public Category(Gender gender, int age, Income income){
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
        this.income = income;
    }
}

enum Income {
    A("A"),
    B("B"),
    C("C");

    private String value;

    Income(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
}

enum Gender {
    MALE("MALE"),
    FEMALE("FEMALE");

    private String value;

    Gender(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Но опять же - это все может быть неправильно, если не указывать предметную область

Answer (score 3):

Segments.Gender - это статический объект, но не тип объекта, не тип переменной.
Если хотите создать массив типа Gender[], то используйте имя класса, где Ваш тип описан (class Category):

```
Category.Gender[] seg = new Category.Gender[2];
```

Comment: А можно как-нибудь изменить класс Segments так, чтобы можно было использовать Segments.Gender как тип?

Comment: Либо Segmentsсделать наследником Category:

class Segments extends Category

Comment: а как мне создать класс Target, в котором будет храниться 
Map<Category, Segment>?

приведу пример - если категория - пол, то сегмент это либо мужчина, либо женщина - как это сделать?

т.е. как сделать так, чтобы сегмент зависел от категории? 
Ну, т.е. чтобы можно было задать как пол так и что-то еще?

Comment: Объявить как `Map<Enum, Segment>`.

Comment: Nofate, так не получится - откуда программа знает что за Enum в Map<Enum, Segments>?

И еще не удасться задать не удасться запихнуть например Segments.Gender.MALE
в Мар - будет ругаться на то, что типы разные...

Comment: > откуда программа знает что за Enum в Map<Enum, Segments>

Все перечисляемые виды в Java являются наследниками класса `Enum`.